# I am facing problem while installing black formatter in vs code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, formatting

WARNING: The scripts black.exe and blackd.exe are installed in 'C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts' which is not on PATH.
Consider adding this directory to PATH or, if you prefer to suppress this warning, use --no-warn-script-location.

need help?

Comment: The warning is clear enough about what you can do. What is your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try the following:

-click on the windows startmenu button and type in  "Edit environment variables for your account"
In the window that shows up select "path" and click on the edit button.

-In the list that show up then add the "C:\Users\hp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\Scripts" path and click OK to save the changes.

After having done that close all your VS code instances and try the formatter again, it should have now have added those scripts to your PATH variable.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).